# Select data from different rows and different columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I want to select all those entries which has following condition: Start date of next row should be Less then 1 month of END Date of the previous row i.e (Startdate (row i ) < Enddate (row i-1)) for the same 'GpID' and 'client id'.

For example in the screenshot below, row with `[ClientGPID] = 2` is invalid because `Startdate` of row with `[ClientGPID] = 2` is `> END date` of row with `[ClientGPID] = 1` for GPID= 67

```
CREATE TABLE [Client_GP]
(
    [ClientGPID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ClientID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [GpID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Startdate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Enddate] [datetime] NULL
)
GO

INSERT INTO [Client_GP] 
VALUES (67, 812, '2016-01-28 16:49:28.000', '2016-01-28 17:52:01.000');

INSERT INTO [Client_GP] 
VALUES(67, 812, '2017-02-24 16:49:28.000', '2017-02-24 17:52:01.000');

INSERT INTO [Client_GP] 
VALUES(67, 812, '2017-02-24 17:52:06.000', NULL);
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Can you show your desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example data that you gave (only three rows), none of the rows are valid.  The first row has no predecessor, the second row is invalid because its `StartDate` value is higher than the `EndDate` value of the previous row, and the same is true of the third row (albeit by 5 seconds).

Just the same, I think this might help you:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
         *
        ,LAG(EndDate) OVER (ORDER BY ClientGPID) AS X
    FROM Client_GP
)
SELECT 
     ClientGPID
    ,ClientID
    ,GpID
    ,Startdate
    ,Enddate
FROM CTE
WHERE StartDate < X
;
```

Played around with some example data and it performed as expected.

The only thing I didn't really understand in your question was this part:

> Start date of next row should be Less then 1 month of END Date of the
>   previous row

What did you mean "Less than 1 month"?

If my answer doesn't work out for you because of this, let me know what you meant so I can give you a complete answer.

Comment: I think he means something like this.. improvising on your answer

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
         *
        ,DATEADD(MM,1,LAG(EndDate) OVER (PARTITION BY CLIENTID, GPID ORDER BY ClientGPID)) AS X
    FROM Client_GP
)
SELECT 
     ClientGPID
    ,ClientID
    ,GpID
    ,Startdate
    ,Enddate
 ,X
FROM CTE
WHERE StartDate < X
;

Comment: However it's worth a mention that LAG would work only in SQL server 2012 and above and not in 2008. For 2008 you could use any option as mentioned here https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/24/sql-server-solution-to-puzzle-simulate-lead-and-lag-without-using-sql-server-2012-analytic-function/

Comment: Thank you 3BK your answer is right. Sam comment is the answer what i was exactly wanted.